# Create a block and name it as an input block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I recently got "assigned" to a piece of code where the following was marked with a `#warning memory leak`

```
- (void)aMethodWithCallback:(BlockType)completedBlock {
        /* Do stuff */
        completedBlock = ^(Class1 *obj, NSError *error) {
            /* Do stuff */
#warning memory leak
            if (completedBlock) {
                completedBlock(obj, error);
            }
         };

         [self callAnotherMethodWithCallback::completedBlock];
    }
```

I'm not sure what to do with it, it looks weird to create a block with the name as the input block, but it seems to work. **Why is the above code dangerous?**

*edit*
ARC is enabled.

Changed the code to this and it doesn't seem to leak anymore:

```
- (void)aMethodWithCallback:(BlockType)completedBlock {
    /* Do stuff */
    BlockType completedBlock2 = ^(Class1 *obj, NSError *error) {
         /* Do stuff */
         if (completedBlock) {
            completedBlock(obj, error);
         }
    };

    [self callAnotherMethodWithCallback::completedBlock2];
}
```

Comment: Is there actually a leak?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Yes, there is. It's minor, but a leak nonetheless.

Comment: @0x7fffffff No, there is no leak. I think the entire question here is bogus. ARC takes care of this 'leak' entirely.

Comment: It's not bogus according to Instruments Leak. @RichardJ.RossIII

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)aMethodWithCallback:(BlockType)completedBlock {
     id obj = nil;
     NSError error = nil;
/* make your stuff with obj and error*/

     if (completedBlock)
        completedBlock(obj, error);

     [self callAnotherMethodWithCallback::completedBlock];
 }
```

Or you will rewrite the variable each time you are invoking the method.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It leaks because the completedBlock is re-assigned. But it only leaks if the block passed as argument was copied before (And how i can know this).

Comment: there is no leak if it is re-assigned, ARC automagically takes care of it. Try running my example (in my answer) with instruments, you will find that there is absolutely no leak.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, there is no leak in the small code snippet you gave. If there was a memory leak, it's not in the snippet of code you provided, as the following program, when compiled with ARC, runs under instruments without issue:

```
void func2(void (^block)(void));

void func1(void (^block)(void))
{
    block = ^() {
        if (block)
            block();
    };

    func2(block);
}

void func2(void (^block)(void)) {
    if (block)
        block();
}

int main()
{
    func1(^{
        NSLog(@"Callback");
    });
}
```

Either I'm missing something, or that piece of code you were "assigned" is bogus.

Note: I would ensure that the scenario being referred to has ARC enabled. If ARC wasn't enabled, then there most definitely *is* a leak in that code.

Comment: It's not bogus, but maybe the problem lies in the parts of the code that I haven't shown here, the /* Do stuff */ parts that is? The /*Do stuff */ code is making use of a third party library...

Comment: @MdaG at any rate, the problem is not with the code you posted.